# Check at compile time if type is pointer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I"m trying to find a way to tell if a type is a pointer at compile time. That is something like this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#if std::is_pointer<char*>::value
#pragma message("blah")
#endif
```

However, this gives "warning C4067: unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive - expected a newline" twice (I think the :: is what confuses it) and it doesn't print blah. When I hoover over ::value the compiler tells me if it's true, which means it's known at compile time so this should work.

The reason for this is that I want to be able to do something like this:

```
T pHead;
#if std::is_pointer<T>::value
pHead= NULL;
#endif
```

where I NULL the variable if it's a pointer. It has to be a compile time check because if T is a struct I cannot assign NULL to its variable. I.e. the following code won't compile when T is a struct:

```
T pHead;
if (std::is_pointer<T>::value)
    pHead= NULL;
```

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can initialize the variable to its default value, which is NULL for a pointer type.

```
T pHead = T();
```

Works for most structs as well.

Comment: I think `T` is a generic. I doubt this will work. What if `T` is `int*`?

Comment: I saw T as a template parameter or a typedef. If it is then it will work. If it actually is `int*` we know it is a pointer and can set it to NULL.

Comment: @Matt - If you have `typedef int* T;` it *does* work. As does a struct or a template parameter.

Comment: As Luchian pointed out, T is generic so it could be a int* or struct so this wouldn't work.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, after testing it does appear to work, I assumed that since int*() doesn't work T() wouldn't work as well . But now why _does_ it work? If int*() doesn't work why would T() when T instantiates as int* work?

Comment: @Matt - A typedef is different than a `#define` in that it is *not* just a text substitution, it actually creates a new name. A typedef name `T` can be used in places where a single token is required, like in `T()`.

Comment: Thanks. I accepted this as the answer now since it does what I need without having to create the two functions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use templates for this:

```
template<typename A>
void foo(A a)
{

}

template<typename A>
void foo(A*& a)
{
   a = NULL;
}
```

Calling foo with a pointer type will enter the second function, otherwise the first one.

You can't do it with preprocessor directives, because, as the name suggests, that happens before compilation.

But template resolution happens during compilation, so you can use this solution.

I'm assuming you're already using templates since your code also provides a generic type:

```
T pHead;
#if std::is_pointer<T>::value
pHead= NULL;
#endif
```

you could use

```
T pHead;
foo(pHead);
```

Comment: Or he can use [boost::is_pointer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_pointer.html).

Comment: It should be `void foo(A*& a)`.

Comment: @elmo I'm guessing that basically applies the same concept, right?

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I guess this is template specialization, which I didn't know much about?

Comment: @Matt - It is not template specialization, just two overloaded functions that happen to be templates.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I guess that principle is the same (guess, because boost implementation is a bit hard to read).

Comment: Ahhh, I should have recognized that it's just function overloading, but the use of template and typename fogged my brain. I'm still pretty new to templates.